# Traverse a file and apply thousand operator for each digit in a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have the file abc.txt with following content

```
CLT_ARAMARK 44294902    21333309    22961593    189.691406  92468
CLT_C2C 11695574    4868496 6827078 279.808594  67159
CLT_CUTTYSARK   2057479 448250  1609229 26.021484   47054
```

I want the output as follows:

```
CLT_ARAMARK 44,294,902  21,333,309  22,961,593  189.691406  92,468
CLT_C2C 11,695,574  4,868,496   6,827,078   279.808594  67,159
CLT_CUTTYSARK   2,057,479   448,250 1,609,229   26.021484   47,054
```

What would be the shortest way to do this? I need minimum line of code.

Comment: And we need you to show at least minimum effort of solving this.

Comment: What I am doing right now is traversing a file and checking for the integer by using regex. [[ $efgh =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]. If it is an integer, I am using thousand seperator  printf "%'.3f\n" $efgh. The point is I have to do this in a efficient way. The braod objective is to print a report with all the numbers with thousand separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) $i=sprintf("%\x27" "d", $i)} 1' file

CLT_ARAMARK 44,294,902 21,333,309 22,961,593 189.691406 92,468
CLT_C2C 11,695,574 4,868,496 6,827,078 279.808594 67,159
CLT_CUTTYSARK 2,057,479 448,250 1,609,229 26.021484 47,054
```

This follows this approach for formatting the numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%\x27" ".3f\n", 12345678.901}'
12,345,678.901
```